# Каков будет синтаксис строки Eloquent/Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, mysqli, eloquent

Я делаю такой запрос:

```
$req = Log::with('users:*');
```

Мне возвращается:

```
data    […]
0   {…}
      id    30

      users {…}
          id    30
          date  2019-01-24
          state User inactive
          user  {…}
            id  1
            login   Vasya
            access  user
```

Как сделать запрос так, чтобы не выводились лишние данные date,access?

```
$req = Log::with('users:?????????');

public function users () 
    {
        return  $this->hasOne('App\Key')->with('user');
    }
public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'user', 'id');
    }
```

В данном примере можно оставить и так, но лишних данных может быть очень много.  Прошу совета.

Comment: $req = Log::with('users:date,access'); не тыкался с логами, но похожая логика в laravel много где, попробуйте так, может поможет

Comment: Так - даёт ошибку Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего будет сделать так:

в модели `Key` добавьте

```
 protected $hidden = ['date'];
```

в модели `User` добавьте

```
 protected $hidden = ['access'];
```

Так вы глобально скроете вывод этих полей при преобразовании этих моделей в массивы.

Если первый способ не подходит, можно список требуемых для вывода полей указать непосредственно через `with()`:

```
$req = Log::with([
    'users' => function($query) {
        $query->select(['id']); // перечень необходимых полей модели Key
    },
    'users.user' => function($query) {
        $query->select(['id', 'login']); // перечень необходимых полей модели User
    },
]);
```